# Написать регулярное выражение для игнорирования внутренних квадратных скобок

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка (для markdown). Нужно вычленить только то, что находится внутри внешних квадратных скобок с помощью регулярного выражения.
Сейчас выражение выглядит так: .match(/[(.*?)]/)?.[1] и выводит только [[Text]

Ввод: [[Text] Text Text Text] (link)

Вывод: [Text] Text Text Text

Comment: Если вложенность только в одни квадратные скобки, то посмотрите на это выражение https://regex101.com/r/nbE9Ur/1

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает в моём кейсе. А есть вариант регулярного выражения для вложенности в нескольких скобках?

Comment: Слава chatGPT
/(?<=\[).*(?=\])/